# I am a new member to Selenium, Help me on the below scenario

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am having two drop down menus. The First Drop Down is called Events and Second Drop Down is called Attributes.
And Events are 47 in numbers and Each corresponding event has 4 attributes.

Now the problem is, I want to write a code like - select the first event and print its corresponding attributes. Similarly select the second event and print all its attributes. All of this should be in a loop.

Please help me on this. Please show me a sample code part.

Comment: You should not ask for a code to complete your tasks, but for advice to improve your own code. So show us code you tried and describe obstacles you encountered

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code. Let me know if it works.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i <47 ; i++)
{
    Select event_DropDown1= new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("<ID for event_DropDown1>")));
    event_DropDown1.selectByIndex(i); 

    Select attributes_DropDown2= new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ID for attributes_DropDown2")));
    /* Getting all options from the  Attributes dropdown */
    List<WebElement> options = dropdown.getOptions();

    /* Loop to print one by one all the options */
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
    {
       System.out.println(options.get(j).getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: please try to verify if this is a solution. otherwise it is not a sufficient answer to this question

Comment: The application is developed by div tags, instead of select tags. So the select class won't work. Let me try it. Then I will share the status. Thank-you so much for giving your help.